# Как правильно сделать два условия в CASE SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

У меня есть CASE который хранит в себе еще один CASE для проверки условий
Мне сказали, что можно сделать без вложенного CASE, как это можно сделать?

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN nspa.id = aal.id THEN
  CASE WHEN
    aal.type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE null
  END
END) as counter
```

Comment: У тебя два отдельных условия. Но `1` ты возвращаешь только если оба они истинны. Почему бы не проверить сразу оба?

Comment: @Akina А как прописать, а то я не понимаю AND же не работает

Comment: а как вы пробовали, что не работает?

Comment: @teran COUNT(CASE WHEN aal.type = 3 AND nspa.id = aal.id THEN 1 ELSE null END)

Comment: @teran Понял проблему, оказалось я не шибко умный, а так все работает

Comment: если использовать такую запись `COUNT(1) filter(where aal.type = 3 AND nspa.id = aal.id) as counter` то код станет и короче, и понятнее